# c++ Looking for a clean and efficient way to get a sub-matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

I am using a vector of vectors to create a 2d array similar to:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > matrix = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9},
        {1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9},
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    };
```

Now I would like to extract a sub-matrix with the specification of:

```
1) all rows
2) the first 4 columns
```

I am new to `c++` so the best I've come up with at now is:

```
if (matrix[n][m-1] >= matrix[n][m])
    {
        std::vector<std::vector<int> > submatrix(3);
        for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
            std::vector<int> slice(m);
            for (int j=0; j < m; j++){
                slice[i] = matrix[i][j];
            }
            submatrix[i] = slice;
        }
        return find_a_peak(submatrix);
    }
```

Where `m` = 4;

This is only for practice, so please suggest a clean way to do this.  I am a python programmer by training, so in `numpy` this is quite easy.  But I would like to learn the basics of `c++` before moving on to third party libraries.

Comment: A `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` should not be taken for a matrix. A wrapper around a single `std::vector<int>` that has a size of `n * m` would be much better. Also a very good exercise!

Comment: It seems, in the inner `for` loop, the assignment should be `slice[j] = matrix[i][j]`.   In tht case, the body of the outer `for` loop can be replaced with `submatrix[i] = std::vector<int>(matrix[i].begin(), matrix[i].begin() + m)`.  Bear in mind this assumes `m` is less than the number of columns in `matrix`.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot can you please elaborate a bit? maybe with a link?

Comment: @SamHammamy A vector of vector represent a dynamically sized array of dynamically sized array. You can easily store all the number of a matrix in a single `std::vector`, which would be more efficient and simpler to deal with. Resizing and allocation would be done in one operation in one vector instead of looping over all sub-vectors. A wrapper around that single vector could implement `operator []` to return a view on a row, and even a `operator *` to allow multiplying matrices.

Comment: @SamHammamy "maybe with a link?" http://stackoverflow.com/a/43552983/4581301 But... [Look at `std::valarray`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) It has all sorts of fun striding and slicing built in.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks for the link! very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the inner loop with a call to `std::vector`'s constructor that takes iterators, and use `std::next` to get the iterator four elements from the beginning:

```
if (matrix[n][m-1] >= matrix[n][m]) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> submatrix;
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        submatrix.push_back(matrix[i].begin(), std::next(matrix[i].begin(), m));
    }
    return find_a_peak(submatrix);
}
```

Comment: using `g++` as a compiler with the `c++11` flag I am getting `error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'
                submatrix.push_back(matrix[i].begin(), std::next(matrix[i].begin(), m));`

Comment: In this, `submatrix` is a function declaration, not a variable.   Look up "most vexing parse".

Comment: @SamHammamy Sorry, I forgot to remove parentheses. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the constructor of `std::vector` that take two iterators as parameter.

```
if (matrix[n][m-1] >= matrix[n][m])
{
   std::vector<std::vector<int> > submatrix; 
    for (int i=0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
        submatrix.push_back(std::vector<int>(matrix[i].begin(), matrix[i].begin() + m));
    }
    return find_a_peak(submatrix);
}
```