# Should I use 1D array to avoid costly mallocations?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want a 2D array with a very big outer dimension, let's say 1 million, and a runtime-determined inner dimension n.

With a vector of vector, I would have to do :

```
for (inner : myvector)
   inner.reserve(n);
```

However this would mean a 1 million memory allocations, which I heard are slow.

Isn't it better to do this instead :

```
myvector = new A[1000000*n];
```

and manually access the element (i,j) with myvector[i*n+j]; despite lesser lisibility

Comment: It's not a bad idea, but why do you think you need `new` for this? You can just as well have a single vector with `1000000*n` elements.

Comment: "which I heard are slow" You heard correctly. Worse you lose spatial locality which can be a persistent bummer as opposed to a one-time cost. Recommend wrapping the vector in a convenience class to make the `myvector[i*n+j];` math transparent and only in one spot. Less room for a hard to find tyop to hide.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley No particular reason, new does the job too though.

Comment: Not as well. You now have a raw pointer to a dynamic allocation. You have to manage the lifetime yourself and take it from just about everybody, it's really easy to screw up.

Comment: [Here's a simple, maybe too simple, example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43552983/4581301) of a `vector` impersonating a matrix.

Comment: If you still want to use `new`, you could also use `std::unique_ptr` or just be careful. That's all.