# How to define a two dimensional array during run time in Visual Studio C++ 11?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am trying to compile [ORBSLAM2](https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2) on Windows with Visual Studio 2015 vc14 x64 compiler. The project was originally developed for GNU GCC. I now have the following issue:

```
// Compute distances between them
const size_t N = vDescriptors.size();

float aDistances[N][N];
for(size_t i=0;i<N;i++) {
    aDistances[i][i]=0;
    for(size_t j=i+1;j<N;j++) {
        int distij = ORBmatcher::DescriptorDistance(vDescriptors[i],vDescriptors[j]);
        aDistances[i][j]=distij;
        aDistances[j][i]=distij;
    }
}
```

I get the this error while compiling:

> C2131 expression did not evaluate to a constant

... on this line of code:

```
const size_t N = vDescriptors.size();
```

Subsequently the two dimensional array definition fails too (`float Distances[N][N];`).

What's the best way to solve this in Visual-C++ ?

**UPDATE:** Here's the complete function code:

```
void MapPoint::ComputeDistinctiveDescriptors() {

    // Retrieve all observed descriptors
    vector<cv::Mat> vDescriptors;
    map<KeyFrame*,size_t> observations;

    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock1(mMutexFeatures);
        if(mbBad)
            return;
        observations=mObservations;
    }

    if(observations.empty())
        return;

    vDescriptors.reserve(observations.size());

    for(map<KeyFrame*,size_t>::iterator mit=observations.begin(), mend=observations.end(); mit!=mend; mit++) {
        KeyFrame* pKF = mit->first;
        if(!pKF->isBad())
            vDescriptors.push_back(pKF->mDescriptors.row(mit->second));
    }

    if(vDescriptors.empty())
        return;

    // Compute distances between them
    const size_t N = vDescriptors.size();

    float aDistances[N][N];
    for(size_t i=0;i<N;i++) {
        aDistances[i][i]=0;
        for(size_t j=i+1;j<N;j++) {
            int distij = ORBmatcher::DescriptorDistance(vDescriptors[i],vDescriptors[j]);
            aDistances[i][j]=distij;
            aDistances[j][i]=distij;
        }
    }

    // Take the descriptor with least median distance to the rest
    int BestMedian = INT_MAX;
    int BestIdx = 0;
    for(size_t i=0;i<N;i++) {
        vector<int> vDists(aDistances[i], aDistances[i]+N);
        sort(vDists.begin(),vDists.end());
        int median = vDists[0.5*(N-1)];
        if(median<BestMedian) {
            BestMedian = median;
            BestIdx = i;
        }
    }

    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(mMutexFeatures);
        mDescriptor = vDescriptors[BestIdx].clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: What about a `float**` initialized with `new float[N][N]`?

Comment: I'd wrap a `std::vector` in a simple class that makes the `vector` [look like a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552819/create-2d-array-using-size-from-parameters-in-c/43552983#43552983). How wedded to the `[][]` notation are you?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: I get the error already at ´const size_t N = vDescriptors.size();´ and ´new float[N][N]´ also requires a constant. So that doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: @user4581301: I am not bound to the `[][]` notation, since the array is only defined and used within a function, so the scope is very manageable. I added the complete function code to the original post.

Comment: this all looks fine. my hunch is that `N` is a macro of some kind, can you rename it to 'foo' and see if that fixes this?

Comment: If you switch from the Error List tab to the Output tab you get a much better description of the problem. It states the error on `const size_t N = vDescriptors.size();` is the result of of how `N` is being used by `float aDistances[N][N];`. In C++ an array MUST be sized with a constant that is known at compile time. You've got a runtime constant and that's not good enough. g++ allows non- constants (Search term: Variable Length Array) for its own nefarious purposes. In this case Visual Studio is adhering closer to the C++ Standard and demanding a compile-time constant.

Comment: @salocinx It would be nice if you state the complete problem right away. If I had seen you tried to compiled existing code, I probably would have answered very differently and it would save me some time. In this case I might even prefer the `Quick Fix`.

Comment: @salocinx What do you mean by `new float[N][N] also rquires a constant`? Heap allocation is dynamic and does not rquire N to be constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your Problem**

You tried to create a 2D array on the stack (this is not standard `C++`, even though it might work on some compilers). For this the size needs to be know at compile time, which is not the case as you call `size()` on an object which likely is not a constexpr.

**QUICK FIX**

A quick fix that works out of the box is to just allocate the memory on the heap (**do not forget to delete array later on**) by doing

```
float** aDistances = new float[N][N];
```

The deletion can be done in a function which looks like this

```
template <typename T>
void delete2DArray(T** ptr, size_t NumRows)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NumRows; i++)
    {
        delete[] ptr[i];
    }
    delete[] ptr;
}
```

**FIX**

You will haveto use dynamic memory allocation. For this you can try the following approach by adding a wrapper class around std::vector (this should be possible as you said the scope is very manageable)

```
template <typename T>
class Array2D
{
public:
    Array2D(size_t numrows, size_t numcols) :
        rows(numrows), columns(numcols), array2d(rows * columns)
    {}

    T& operator()(size_t row, size_t column)
    {
        return array2d[row * columns + column]; 
    }

    const T& operator()(size_t row, size_t column) const
    {
        return array2d[row * columns + column];
    }

    T* getRow(size_t row)
    {
        return &array2d[row * columns];
    }


private:
    size_t rows;
    size_t columns;
    std::vector<T> array2d;
};
```

Than you have to modify your code like this:

```
// Compute distances between them
const size_t N = vDescriptors.size();

Array2D<float> aDistances(N,N);
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    aDistances(i,i) = 0;
    for (size_t j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
        int distij = ORBmatcher::DescriptorDistance(vDescriptors[i], vDescriptors[j]);
        aDistances(i,j) = distij ;
        aDistances(j,i) = distij ;
    }
}
```

As you can see the syntax to access elements has slightly changed [x][y] -> (x,y).

**EDIT**

As the OP has modified the question, I have noticed that the `Distances` is used a second time which needs attention as well. For this you will have to add a `getColumn` method (see above) to the `Array2D` class. Than you further have to modify

```
// Take the descriptor with least median distance to the rest
int BestMedian = INT_MAX;
int BestIdx = 0;
for(size_t i=0;i<N;i++) {
    vector<int> vDists(aDistances.getRow()[i], aDistances.getRow()[i]+N);
    sort(vDists.begin(),vDists.end());
    int median = vDists[0.5*(N-1)];
    if(median<BestMedian) {
        BestMedian = median;
        BestIdx = i;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I am not perfectly sure if I got it right -- maybe you have to get a 
columns instead of a rows (too late to think straight). If this is the case you should also change the memory layout of the Array2D class, i.e. sorting the elements differently in the underlaying 1D-Vector.

Comment: @P i: Strange, if I am using the Quick Fix approach, I get another `expression must have a constant value` for `float** aDistances = new float[N][N];` pointing to `[N][N]`. I removed `const` from `size_t N = vDescriptors.size();`.

Comment: Great, I managed to build the project according to your help! Thank you!

Comment: @salocinx Great to hear!